# C to Python Anagrams

Tags: python, c, indexing

I am trying to learn Python. Consider this simple anagram checker in C:

```
bool are_anagrams(const char* str1, const char* str2)
{
  int str1_count[NUM_CHARS] = {0};
  int str2_count[NUM_CHARS] = {0};

  for(int i = 0; i < strlen(str1); i++)
  {
    str1_count[str1[i] - 'a']++;
  } 
  for(int i = 0; i < strlen(str2); i++)
  {
    str2_count[str2[i] - 'a']++;
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < NUM_CHARS; i++)
  {
    if(str1_count[i] != str2_count[i])
      { return false; }
  }

  return true;
}
```

Specifically, how is the line `str1_count[str2[i] - 'a']++` done in Python?

Comment: Key to translating code: (1) Translate C to English (or whatever your native language is).  (2) Translate English to Python.

Comment: Translating code *directly* between languages only works well when the languages are quite similar. To translate the C `are_anagrams` function to Python you're much better served getting the concept in your mind of what `are_anagrams` does as a high level operation and writing a Python function to do that. The individual operations making up `are_anagrams` will not necessarily translate well to Python. *Trying* to translate the individual operations is a terrible way to learn a new language, since you don't yet know enough to recognise when you're "going against the grain".

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I'd have to disagree. I'd say, "Translate your *intent* to %(language)s, then translate %(language)s to Python."

Comment: @kojiro, The problem is deciding on the chunk size of the problem to translate at once. In this case `str1_count[str2[i] - 'a']++` is too small, and the function is probably about right size. In real life code "one function" isn't always the best chunk though

Comment: @gnibbler In principle, I agree, but you're generalizing the problem well beyond the scope of this question. Here, we have someone *trying to learn Python* who has narrowed his question down to the point where to answer it precisely would be less helpful than to infer his intent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or even better,

```
def are_anagrams(s1, s2):
    return sorted(s1)==sorted(s2)
```

.

**Edit:** in response to @gnibbler:

Here's a quick run-time comparison, where x axis gives string length; blue is your function, green is mine. Both look pretty linear to me.

[image: graph comparing function run-times]

Comment: Despite the fact this doesn't answer the question asked, I think this answer does a good job of illustrating that the specific question asked is an [X-Y problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341)

Comment: But it turns an O(n) problem into a O(n*log n) :)

Comment: @gnibbler: for reasonable anagram lengths, this should not be a problem. If you are regularly dealing with thousand-letter anagrams, you can worry about it.

Comment: @HughBothwell, I'm pretty sure that the sort algorithm actually _becomes_ O(n)  or close to it once n gets to the thousands, since pool of distinct values is quite small.

Comment: @gnibbler: so... what were you complaining about, again??

Answer (score 5):

> Specifically, how is the line `str1_count[str2[i] - 'a']++` done in Python?

It isn't. Python has `dict` for handling things like this.

```
str1_count = {}
 ...
str1_count[char2] += 1
```

Although `collections.defaultdict` is usually used to handle the case where it's a new key.

```
str1_count = collections.defaultdict(int)
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider this simple anagram checker in Python

```
from collections import Counter
def are_anagrams(str1, str2):
    return Counter(str1) == Counter(str2)
```

How would you convert that to C? (This is using the same algorithm as your C version)

To answer your question, you'd have to use `ord()`

```
str1_count[ord(str2[i]) - ord('a')]
```

Looks like a bug slipped in there with str1/str2 naming though